# In java, it is posible to define the persistence version attribute over a type obtained using generics?

Tags: java, generics, jpa

Maybe the question itself is not very clear. I will explain it. I have some basic classes to define entities extending from them with the objetive of avoiding recoding always the same basic things. In this case I have the class:

```
package libs.data.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Access;
import javax.persistence.AccessType;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;
import javax.persistence.Version;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@MappedSuperclass
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public abstract class ExtendedEntity<ID extends Serializable, VERSION extends Number> extends SimpleEntity<ID>
{

    @Version
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "CurVer", nullable = false)
    protected VERSION curVer;       // Current Version

    public ExtendedEntity()
    {
        id = null;
        curVer = null;
    }

    public VERSION getCurVer()
    {
        return curVer;
    }

    public void setCurVer(VERSION curVer)
    {
        this.curVer = curVer;
    }

}
```

In this class the ID and the VERSION are generic types that I can set when I define the entity class. The @version annotation alerts me that it isn't a valid type for a version attribute, but I supposed that if declare the class Person using Long class for the ID and the VERSION it should work. When I try to launch the web application in a glassfish server (4.x), it generates the error:

```
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-7168] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: The attribute [curVer] of type [class java.lang.String] on the entity class [class es.nextel.libs.data.entities.ExtendedEntity] is not valid for a version property. The following types are supported: int, Integer, short, Short, long, Long, Timestamp.
at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException.invalidTypeForVersionAttribute(ValidationException.java:1153)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.VersionAccessor.process(VersionAccessor.java:122)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataDescriptor.processMappingAccessors(MetadataDescriptor.java:1536)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.ClassAccessor.processMappingAccessors(ClassAccessor.java:1648)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.MappedSuperclassAccessor.processMetamodelDescriptor(MappedSuperclassAccessor.java:1219)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProject.processStage2(MetadataProject.java:1784)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProcessor.processORMMetadata(MetadataProcessor.java:576)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.processORMetadata(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:585)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1869)
... 62 more
```

Thank you in advance and sorry about my english.

Comment: Check if your column @Column(name = "CurVer", nullable = false) is not a string type in DB.

Comment: It is not a string type column.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the exception message you can only extend the following values for `VERSION` i.e. `int, Integer, short, Short, long, Long, Timestamp`. Therefore, you can not add the `extends Number` after the `VERSION`. You will have to just make it a untyped generic. You're implementing classes will have to ensure that they use one of the valid types.

Comment: Yes, I see that. But expected that if I define a class ExtendedLongIdEntity as `public abstract class ExtendedLongIdEntity extends ExtendedEntity<Long, Long>` it could work. I will try what you mention.

Comment: I removed ` extends Number` and it continues generating the same error when I try to deploy the app.